# A "Forest control" for .NET: A usercontrol that can display X nodes where each node may have a connection to another?

Tags: .net, user-controls

I have a structure I need to visualize. It contains of a set of nodes, where each node has a connection to one of the other nodes. A treeview can not show this as the connection does not follow a treeview structure.

Does anyone know of a control that might be able to show this? The best way to illustrate the node connections is like when you show a class diagram in .NET. Each class comes up with lines to what other classes they are connected to.

I just need a very simple way to show this. Simple boxes with or without info that connects to other boxes that again connects to other boxes.

Simply illustrated here:

```
       [D]--->[E]
        ^      |
        |      |
        |      v
[A]<---[B]--->[C]
```

[Solution using GLEE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx)

Add a GViewer to your usercontrol.
Then to reproduce my ABCDE example over, only this is needed:

```
Graph g = new Graph("graph");
g.AddEdge("B","A");
g.AddEdge("B", "C");
g.AddEdge("B", "D");
g.AddEdge("D", "E");
g.AddEdge("E", "C");

myGViewer.Graph = g;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "forest" sounds just like a [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) (digraph). Google it.
First results page comes up with:

1. [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/Wikipage)
2. [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Automatic_Graph_Layout)

Comment: Seems like what I am after. Checking it out.

Comment: Seems the free GLEE component from MSAGL is the one I can use:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx

Comment: I also found out MSAGL is available for download under MSDN Subscribtions. Seems they have added a few new things like picture support.